# If $f(x)=2x+3$ if $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=3x+3$ when $x>0$. Find $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

If $f(x)=2x+3$ if $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=3x+3$ when $x>0$. Find $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$.

If we want to evaluate the left hand limit and right hand limit respectively  then which condition should we apply. I mean if $x\to 1-$ takes into account $\lim_{x\to 1-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1-}2x+3=5$ . On the other hand, $x\to 1+$ then, $\lim_{x\to 1+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1+}3x+3=6$ . However, why are we taking $2x+3$ when $x\to 1-$. Actually,  $x\to 1-$ means $x=1-h$ where $h\to 0$. So what's the reason for taking this function when applying $x\to 1-$. If $x\to 0-$ then we must have taken $f(x)=2x+3$ . But why are taking $f(x)=2x+3$ when $x\to 1-$? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: when x approaches 1 from the left, it is only a tiiiiiiiiny bit less than 1. Hence x is positive. Don’t use 2x+3

Comment: @insipidintegrator That's my point ...we must not  take $2x+3$ when $x\rightarrow 1-$. But the book follows this function when $x\rightarrow 1-$...so the thing is not correct, right?Which means we must use $3x+3$ for both the left hand limit and right hand limit, which implies the limit exists ,right?

Comment: Please edit the question to add the source of your question and where 2x+3 has been used. As you say, for x approaching  $0^-$ it will be appropriate to take two different values.

Comment: No, it is not correct. Probably a typo that should have been either x$\rightarrow$0 or the comditions on the piecewise function should be wrt x> and < 1.

Comment: @insipidintegrator So the limit exists and  $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1-}3x+3=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1+}3x+3=6$. This is the correct way right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}2x + 3,\ x \le 0\\3x + 3,\ x > 0\end{cases}$$
For both LHL as well as RHL, the definition $f(x) = 3x + 3$ where $x > 0$ has to be considered.

For LHL, i.e. when $x \to 1^-$ and for RHL, i.e. when $x \to 1^+$, these both quantities are greater than $0$.

> Don't get confused between $-1$ and $1^-$.

- $1^-$ is a value slightly smaller than $1$, for instance $0.000000000000000000099$. It is not equivalent to $-1$.

Comment: So the limit exists and  $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1-}3x+3=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1+}3x+3=6$. This is the correct way right?

Comment: @Franklin Yeah, that's correct!

Comment: Thank you so much! I do get it now...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Franklin After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Yeah, accepting an answer is great but we can accept it after 5 minutes so grnerally a user does not hold on for 5 minutes ...that quite unusual atleast for me...so next time when a user reopens the site he accepts the answer...and that's quite natural I suppose...owing to the guidelines presented in the site

Answer (score 0):

For $x=1>0$ then $$f(x)=3x+3$$ in this case, and so $$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)=\lim_{x \to 1} (3x+3)=3(1)+3=6$$ since $x \mapsto 3x+3$ is a lineal function (and therefore continuous).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} f(x)=f(1)=6$, since it is continuous and linear for $x=1$.